# Is it possible to manipulate the index parameter of Array.prototype.reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, ecmascript-5

Normally the index value of Array.prototype.reduce takes the values from 0 until the Array.length.
Is it possible to manipulate that value so that it starts from Array.length and descends to 0?

Comment: Can't you just reverse the array?

Comment: Or use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)?

Comment: Or the [`english one`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) for this.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could always do this...

```
var yourNumber = arr.length - 1 - index;
```

...or `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` which will loop from last index to first (in reverse).